# Transfer large messages with Apache CXF

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, large-data-volumes

I'm writing a CXF WS to upload some large files - up to 1GB. In most cases they won't be >10-15MB, but the problem is that it is ineffective to load the file and send it as regular byte[] using the standard binding. For that reason a custom interceptor might be needed but I'm not sure it is the only option as well as how to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CXF supports the [MTOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism) specification, which as well as providing a more transmission-efficient encoding for binary data, but also provides a more flexible API for [binding using JAXB](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom-attachments-with-jaxb.html). This decouples the binary data from `byte[]` and replaced it with a `DataHandler`, which allows you to source the data from streams, rather than `byte[]`. This applies both to client and server ends of the connection.